# existence of unique fixed point

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $(X,d)$ be a compact metric space and $f:X \to X$ satisfies $d(f(x), f(y))< d(x,y)$ for distinct $x$ and $y$. Then, show that $f$ has a unique fixed point. 
I tried this question by formulating a function $g$ on $X$ defined as $g(x)= d(x, f(x))$, then it is a continuous function on a compact set hence attains its bound. But how to show that the infimum is zero?

Answer (score 2):

Assume the minimum of $g(x) = d(x,f(x))$ is $m > 0$, and let the minimum be attained at $a$. Then consider $g(f(a))$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: suppose that the infimum (minimum) is reached at $x_0$. Can you find points closer than $x_0$ and $f(x_0)$?

Answer (score 1):

Assume there are two fixed points $x_1,x_2\in X$, then for some $K\in[0,1)$ we have $$0\le d(x_1,x_2)= d(f(x_1),f(x_2))\le Kd(x_1,x_2)$$
$$\Rightarrow 0\le (1-K)d(x_1,x_2)\le 0$$
Where $(1-K)\ne 0$